# Trouble importing jaxxwallet into Mist

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-key

I cant´t import the keyfile from jaxx via geth into Mist. I know there are good answers here already. And i tried to solve it myself but it always says:" Fatal: keyfile must be given as argument". I`m using windows 7. Any help? Thx

Comment: Have you followed a particular set of instructions? Which answers have you already looked at?